# Arel -- how to convert column to current timezone & truncate milliseconds

Tags: activerecord, arel, rails-activerecord

I've been trying to find detailed Arel documentation, but in vain. Finally I tried digging into the source code and figured ou

The following works (note the to_sql in the end):

```
Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new('to_char', Audit.arel_table[:created_at], 'dd-mm-yyyy').to_sql
```

And, the following works:

```
tzdate = Arel::Nodes::InfixOperation.new('at time zone', Arel::Nodes::InfixOperation.new('at time zone', Audits.arel_table[:created_at], 'gmt'), Time.zone.tzinfo.name)
```

The following, does NOT work (note the to_sql in the end) due to `TypeError: Cannot visit Arel::Nodes::InfixOperation`:

```
Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new('to_char', [tzdate, 'dd-mm-yyyy']).to_sql
```

Can anyone tell me what is happening here?

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues here:

- You need to wrap the date format string with `Arel.new('dd-mm-yyyy')` (which produces an `Arel::Nodes::SqlLiteral`).
- The time zone strings need to be quoted (e.g. `Arel::Nodes::Quoted.new('UTC')`). See https://github.com/rails/arel/issues/323